# Show user error message if form is not filled via HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to create the functionality so that a user is returned to the url with an error message if they don't fill in the forms.

My urls

```
from django.urls import path
from content import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('readerpage/<int:content_id>', views.readerpage, name='readerpage'),
    path('readerpage/<int:content_id>/add_review',
         views.add_review, name='add_review'),
]
```

My view

```
def add_review(request, content_id):
content = get_object_or_404(Content, pk=content_id)
if request.POST['readability'] and request.POST['readability_rating'] and request.POST['actionability'] and request.POST['actionability_rating'] and request.POST['general_comments']:
    review = Review()
    review.readability = request.POST['readability']
    review.readability_rating = request.POST['readability_rating']
    review.actionability = request.POST['actionability']
    review.actionability_rating = request.POST['actionability_rating']
    review.general_comments = request.POST['general_comments']
    review.avg = (float(review.readability_rating) +
                  float(review.actionability_rating)) / 2
    review.content = content
    review.save()
    return redirect('home')
else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('readerpage', args=(content_id,)))
```

Right now the user gets returned but doesn't get an error message

I've tried with the return render, instead of the HttpResponseRedirect

```
return render (request, 'content/readerpage', {'error': 'You need to fill in all information'})
```

But that send the user to the wrong url, creating an error, as it adds the add_review to the to URL

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/content/readerpage/41/add_review
```

Is there any way to pass along the error with the HttpResponseRedirect?
Or is there another alternative?

Thanks for reading this

Comment: I'd suggest to use a [django form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/) you get validation, error messages, instance creation, etc for free

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to create the functionality so that a user is returned to the url with an error message if they don't fill in the forms.

This is one of the main reasons to use Django for, so you should not try to re-implement the wheel at this point.

Use Django's generic views for your models, they will setup form validation and redirection as is convention, and just like you have described in your request.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/

Saves you lots of code, tests, and problems.